# Run PowerShell script in window on machine

Tags: windows, powershell, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to have a PowerShell script run after a machine restart. I want the script to run on restart, not login. Additionally, I want the script to run in a window. I found many questions that are almost identical to mine but don't include having the script running in a window. I've tried including `-noexit`. I have tried to use task scheduler and while it says that my script is running, no window appears. What do I need to do to make it run in a window?

I do not want to change global keys making all scripts run in a window and I do not want to write anything in my script that prompts the user to close the window.

Comment: When a machine (re)starts, there is no interactive session yet, so no visible windows. Try AutoAdminLogon

Comment: If you want to see what happens in the console window just have the script start a transcript (`Start-Transcript`) as the first line in the script. Then you can read what you would have seen at your leisure.

Comment: I want to see if the script is running correctly. It is being used all day and I just want to keep my eye one it. @ddug Is there a way to have the windows ready to open once I am logged in? Or will I need to set an automatic logon for this to work?

Comment: There's no window available before login, because there is no user who could see the window before login.

Comment: Could you have the first script save out the status into readable location (registry/file/event log) then have a second script display out the status?

Comment: If it is being run all day then have it write to a transcript and have another console where you are tailing the transcript. Unless you mean it is being run on different computers repeatedly. In which case there would be a possibility of file locking in which case each computer would need to write their own transcript and you could have a second script summarizing results from the transcripts.

Comment: @EBGreen Thanks. That is ultimately what I decided to do. Nice to have someone else say it though.